# How to make Keras RNN to work with real-time generating sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to create a RNN which will play tetris. I'm using evolutionary methods, so I have no option to create a dataset with field state sequences associated with right decision sequences.

So, the behavior that I need to get from the neural network is the following:

1. Create a RNN model
2. Give it a single input (current field state) and take an answer that **takes into account previous moves**
3. Use the neural network response to make a move in the game
4. Get new game field state, pass it to the neural network, repeat from point (2)

The problem is that on the same inputs I get the same outputs, which indicates that the RNN does not take into account its previous actions:

```
model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True) ,
            layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True) ,
            layers.Dense(3, input_dim =10, activation='softmax')
        ]
    )

    x1 = np.ones((1, 1, inp_size))
    
    y1 = model(x1)
    y2 = model(x1)
    y3 = model(x1)

    print(y1)
    print(y2)
    print(y3)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([[[0.23550956 0.5169458  0.24754472]]], shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[0.23550956 0.5169458  0.24754472]]], shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[[0.23550956 0.5169458  0.24754472]]], shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)
```

So, when i do the same thing, but feed input as a sequence packed to tensor:

```
x = np.ones((1, 3, inp_size))
y = model(x)
print(y)
```

I get different results on the same inputs:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.23801968 0.4496906  0.31228966]
  [0.30908147 0.3184522  0.37246636]
  [0.2849004  0.5014079  0.21369171]]], shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

How can I create a RNN model which will not need a full game history as an input sequence to take proper decisions? The question is about opportunity to force network to work step by step, as if processing the sequence, but at the same time receiving only a SINGLE element at the input and immediately giving an answer (since the n-th element of the input sequence depends on the n-1 network output, and we cannot get it until previous output will not be processed by the game)

Comment: You are putting the exact same random data through the exact same network 3 times; why would you expect them to be different?

Comment: Because at the first run neurons in the layer are zero, on the second run then there should stay some numbers from previous run, so the answer should be different due to different recurrent layer state

Comment: Based on what you have written above, you have instantiated a network with random weights. Then you are passing the same data in 3 times. You are not doing any optimizations in between, therefore the weights of the network are not changing. So it will produce the same answer each time.

Comment: I am working with reccurrent network, so its output depends not only on the input values and weights, but also on the earlier input data.
So, when i do the same thing, but feed input as a sequence packed to tensor:
```
x = np.ones((1, 3, inp_size))
y = model(x)
print(y)
```
I get different results on the same outputs:
```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.23801968 0.4496906  0.31228966]
  [0.30908147 0.3184522  0.37246636]
  [0.2849004  0.5014079  0.21369171]]], shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
```